# Xamarin LINQ to Objects support

Tags: c#, .net, linq, xamarin

Is there LINQ support for querying object collection (LINQ to Objects) in Xamarin Android or iOS?  It seem like it's mostly LINQ to SQL or something like that?  They include queries in their demo, but it's mostly querying from a table:

```
Table<Entity>
```

And I saw a LINQ query for querying XML, but is there native collection support, and how do you enable it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, monotouch/xamarin.ios does support linq to objects. I believe all you need to do to support it is add using System.Linq.

For example, from the [Introduction To MonoTouch.Dialog](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/monotouch.dialog):

> Via the clever usage of LINQ and C#’s initialization syntax, LINQ can
>   be used to create an element hierarchy. For example, the following
>   code creates a screen from some string arrays and handles cell
>   selection via an anonymous function that is passed into each
>   StringElement:

```
var rootElement = new RootElement ("LINQ root element") {
from x in new string [] { "one", "two", "three" }
select new Section (x) {
from y in "Hello:World".Split (':')
select (Element) new StringElement (y,
delegate { Debug.WriteLine("cell tapped"); })
}
};
```